# How do I program an offline form of the crucial memory scanner

Tags: c++, windows, memory

I like the memory scanner you can get from crucial (http://www.crucial.com/systemscanner/index.aspx) however it only works with an online computer.

I would like to be able to do as much as possible of what it does, but off-line.

I would like to produce sufficient info to be able to take this info to another online computer and use that to order a memory upgrade.

I would like to program this making minimum assumptions about what is on the target computer.

My language of choice would be C++.

(C# is my current favorite language but using this would require the .Net environment which is an assumption too far for my liking.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WMI (in the root\cimv2 namespace) has the Win32_MemoryArray, Win32_MemoryDevice, Win32_MemoryDeviceArray, Win32_PhysicalMemory and Win32_PhysicalMemoryArray classes (and a couple of others). These might help.